# Set yticklabels to strings

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have cell array from data set as below.

```
a = [datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15, 14, 57, 23, 793), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15, 15, 42, 58, 448), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15, 15, 44, 46, 892), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15, 15, 45, 10, 770), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15, 15, 45, 23, 33), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15, 15, 45, 53, 582), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15, 15, 46, 17, 582), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15, 15, 46, 21, 676), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15, 15, 47, 1, 246), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15, 15, 47, 27, 558)]
b = [5, 4, 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 4, 6]

plt.plot(a,b,'ro-')
```

This plots well but I want to show string on map whenever specific number is seen.

e.g.  4--> apple 5 --> mango and 6 --> orange

Is it possible with `matplotlib.pyplot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the by setting the `yticklabels`

```
plt.gca().set_yticks([4,5,6]) 
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(["apple", "mango", "orange"])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

looks like `annotate` is what you want:

[Matplotlib: How to put individual tags for a scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147112/matplotlib-how-to-put-individual-tags-for-a-scatter-plot)

[Label python data points on plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272081/label-python-data-points-on-plot)

[matplotlib scatter plot with different text at each data point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point)

Comment: May be I was not clear in my description. I want to tag number with particular string on y axis. Y -axis should be apple, mango and orange instead of numbers.