# Python matplotlib: add count number on top of the bar

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the following matplotlib code:

```
ax = my_df.plot(x='arrival_month', y='my_count' ,kind='bar', figsize =  (20,10), fontsize = 16, color = 'b', alpha = 0.3)  
ax.set_xticklabels([t.get_text().split(" ")[0] for t in ax.get_xticklabels()])
ax.set_ylim([-50,300])
plt.show()
```

generates the figure:

[image]

I am wondering is it possible to add the count number on top of the bar like:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Something like looping over

> `ax.annotate('(%s, %s)' % xy, xy=xy, textcoords='data')`

should work, where `xy` are tuples representing the x- and y-value of each coordinate.

This has been suggested in an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272081/label-python-data-points-on-plot).

If you give a MWE, we could also test our suggestions. Especially telling us what exactly `my_df` looks like, would help.