# How to annotate data points

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

I want to label each data point on my pyplot.

I have two sets of data and I would like to label each data point with their value.

This is my code:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 x_position = [1,6,2,7,4,5]
 y_position = [8,4,7,7,2,4]

 plt.plot(x_position, y_position, 'rx')
 plt.show()
```

This plots a graph with a red marker for each point, however I need the data points to be displayed at each point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22272081/5195706) should give you what you need.

Comment: @saintsfan342000 Well spotted. Next time you may directly vote to close the question as duplicate; this makes it much easier for everyone.

Comment: @Importance Thanks, will do.  I (incorrectly) assumed I didn't have sufficient rep to do that, but see now that I do.

Answer (score 3):

Use `plt.annotate`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_position = [1,6,2,7,4,5]
y_position = [8,4,7,7,2,4]

plt.plot(x_position, y_position, 'rx')

labels = ['text{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(x_positions))]
for label, x, y in zip(labels, x_position, y_position):
    plt.annotate(label, xy=(x, y), xytext=(2, 2),
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Instead of providing an answer to a question which has obviously already been asked before please simply mark as duplicate.