# Plotting buy-sell signals on time series data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time-series, visualization

I'm trying to plot a time series data so that I can display buy and sell points on the data itself.

This is how the data looks like:

[image: Dataframe]

This is the close price line chart:

[image: Close price line chart]

This is the buy sell signals (I'm only printing buy sell signals for now but I'm going to store them into a new dataframe):

[image: Buy_Sell Prints]

I'm not trying to label `every` data point but the points in my `buy-sell list`. I need to match the dates in both dataframes and add a green up-arrow for buys, red down-arrow for sells. An example solution:

[image: Buy-sell signals on historical data]

How can I do this?

Comment: With ax.annotate. https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html What happens when you try that?

Comment: I'm very new to matplotlib. I researched and tried `markevery` option but did not yield what I wanted. Can you give me a working example?

Comment: Lots of generic examples on the linked page. For something more specific, add some of your code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using pyplot from matplotlib. If that's the case there's already a solution for that here: [Label python data points on plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272081/label-python-data-points-on-plot/22272358)

If you want something with a bit more detail Matplotlib has a page on this themselves as well. They show you how to use the arrows that you have in this example: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html

Comment: I'm not trying to label `every` data point but the points in my `buy-sell list`. I need to match the date and add a green up-arrow for buys, red down-arrow for sells

Comment: You could add another series to the same plot with only the points you're interested in labeling.

Comment: That's exactly what the Matplotlib tutorial shows- you specify each point that you want to be labled like this: ``ax.annotate('axes fraction',
            xy=(3, 1), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(0.8, 0.95), textcoords='axes fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='top') `` where xy=(3,1) specifies the point at (3,1). You could iterate through your buy-sell list and populate that xy field with each value you have. Then just use an offset to get the label where you want it.